# Flutter : How to add item's ID into List of String

Tags: flutter, dart

I've create a List of String  `List<String> favId;` to get the ID of list item when the user click favorite icon. But when I write the code like this :

```
GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      doa.fav ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: doa.fav ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      doa.fav = !doa.fav;
                      favId.add(doa.id.toString());
                    }),
                  ),
            )
```

the compiler was error and show this message :

```
The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add("2")
```

How can I fix my code so the item's Id that user clicked will added into favId.
Here is the preview when the IconButton was cliked :

[image]

Comment: Where is your `favId` initialized?

Comment: here is my full code https://replit.com/@nabilrei/Bill-Rei-problems#detailDoaPage.dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just define it by `List<String> favId` because favId will be null and when you add a new data it will be an errror say as `null`. You must define it `List<String> favId = []` and when you add a new data the error will gone.

Answer (score 1):

you must initialize favId like this.

List  favId=[];